# Make div to stay in the container

Tags: css

I want to put a button on an image, but if the image have < height than id="addgravity" top:-300px, the button will go out from the container.

```
<div class="item">
    <img src=""/><hr style="position: relative;top:-20px;"/>
    <div id="addgravity" style="position:relative;top:-300px;background:white;
    height:56px;color:white;opacity:0.9;"class="item">button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the 'addgravity' div need to appear in the bottom of the markup?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking. Do you mean how do you display the 3 divs vertically aligned like rows in a table?

Comment: @Drew container -> image->id="addgravity" . I want to make an example of how the width of an image can get out the id="addgravity" from container if I add style top -300px

Comment: As it stands neither your question or your comment make sense. Voting to close. Please improve your description of the problem.

Comment: @Skyfall I want to put a button on image, but if the image have < height than id="addgravity" top:-300px, the button will go out from the container.

Comment: So show us the markup where you have an image and a button!

Comment: @Moob I added the markup in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it difficult for yourself by using negative margins to position things. Why not position the 'button' absolutely so that it stays aligned in the middle regardless of the image size?

```css
.item {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#addgravity {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    background:white;
    height:56px;
    color:black;
    opacity:0.9;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <div id="addgravity">button</div>
</div>
```